# Static bootstrap template works on webserver but not locally on IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I have a strange issue. I'm loading the jumbotron bootstrap 3 template.

here:
http://onlyslightly.com/rethemetest/jumbotron3.html

It seems to work fine in IE8 when I visit it, however when I load it locally it is no longer responsive. The columns are stacked on top of each other instead of three of them side by side.

To make sure it wasn't an issue where an external js file wasn't being blocked, I added each file locally.

Any ideas about what could possible cause this?

Comment: Is IE running in compatibility mode?

Comment: No 404s in the console?

Comment: Your JS responsive shim is not working locally due to IE security settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are directly opening the HTML in the browser and checking it.

You need to have a web server in your system so that you can run the same HTML in localhost.

You can install apache web server in your system.